# Usage of DynamoDB as Key/Value store like redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to use DynamoDB like a key value store in the same way I would use Redis?

DynamoDB requires you to define at minimum a partition & optionally a sort key to form your primary key, but does the attribute name for my partition key have to correspond to an attribute present in the data I'm storing against it?

For instance, is it possible to simply do:

```
amazonDB.putItem("myUniqueKey", arbitraryJson)

amazonDB.getItem("myUniqueKey")
```

where `myUniqueKey` has zero relation to any specific attribute in my arbitrary JSON named something like `MyUniqueKey`?

I have been told this is possible but haven't seen any examples or explanations on how to achieve this through AWS documentation.

Comment: With what purpose are you storing key value pairs in DynamoDB if I may ask?